# How to get content to fill up entire button in XAML?

Tags: xaml, uwp, blend

I have a UWP application, where I want a path to be the content of a button. So far, this is what I have:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="arrow">
   <Setter Property="Content">
      <Setter.Value>
          <Path Height="10" Width="10" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Black" Data="F1 M 92.362,56.1133C 93.8282,57.8717 92.9765,60.7721 90.4336,60.7721L 80.461,60.7721L 80.461,103.953C 80.461,105.441 79.22,106.682 77.7318,106.682L 55.6016,106.682C 54.1133,106.682 52.8718,105.441 52.8718,103.953L 52.8718,60.7721L 42.8997,60.7721C 40.3575,60.7721 39.5052,57.8717 40.972,56.1133L 64.7376,27.5612C 65.3184,26.8627 66.0052,26.6081 66.6667,26.6536C 67.3282,26.6081 68.0131,26.8627 68.5964,27.5612L 92.362,56.1133 Z M 66.6667,0C 103.484,0 133.333,29.8476 133.333,66.6667C 133.333,103.486 103.484,133.333 66.6667,133.333C 29.8483,133.333 0,103.486 0,66.6667C 0,29.8476 29.8483,0 66.6667,0 Z M 66.6667,122.667C 97.5938,122.667 122.667,97.5938 122.667,66.6667C 122.667,35.739 97.5938,10.6667 66.6667,10.6667C 35.7389,10.6667 10.6667,35.739 10.6667,66.6667C 10.6667,97.5938 35.7389,122.667 66.6667,122.667 Z "/>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the button:
`<Button Height="13" Width="13" Style="{StaticResource arrow}">`

However, the path doesn't show. Further investigating reveals that the path gets cut off at smaller sizes and works as content on the larger sizes. I suspect it might have to do with some kind of content padding. How do I make the path fill up the button instead of getting cut off?

Answer (score 0):

You have solved it yourself - it's a padding problem (*Button* has a default one - just change it to 0). I've tried like this and it should work:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="arrow">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Path Height="10" Width="10" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Black" Data="F1 M 92.362,56.1133C 93.8282,57.8717 92.9765,60.7721 90.4336,60.7721L 80.461,60.7721L 80.461,103.953C 80.461,105.441 79.22,106.682 77.7318,106.682L 55.6016,106.682C 54.1133,106.682 52.8718,105.441 52.8718,103.953L 52.8718,60.7721L 42.8997,60.7721C 40.3575,60.7721 39.5052,57.8717 40.972,56.1133L 64.7376,27.5612C 65.3184,26.8627 66.0052,26.6081 66.6667,26.6536C 67.3282,26.6081 68.0131,26.8627 68.5964,27.5612L 92.362,56.1133 Z M 66.6667,0C 103.484,0 133.333,29.8476 133.333,66.6667C 133.333,103.486 103.484,133.333 66.6667,133.333C 29.8483,133.333 0,103.486 0,66.6667C 0,29.8476 29.8483,0 66.6667,0 Z M 66.6667,122.667C 97.5938,122.667 122.667,97.5938 122.667,66.6667C 122.667,35.739 97.5938,10.6667 66.6667,10.6667C 35.7389,10.6667 10.6667,35.739 10.6667,66.6667C 10.6667,97.5938 35.7389,122.667 66.6667,122.667 Z "/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="14" Width="14" Style="{StaticResource arrow}"/>
</Grid>
```